# Python: Using exception for iteration (beginner)

Tags: python, iteration

I just want to know why this doesn't work
(I am trying to name the ducklings from a book: Jack, Kack, Lack, Mack, Nack, Ouack, Pack, Quack) Note: Quack and Ouack have a U

```
prefixes = 'JKLMNOPQ'
suffix = 'ack'

for letter in prefixes:
    if letter != 'O' or 'Q':      #I know this doesn't work, need to know alternative
        print letter + suffix
    else:
        print letter + 'u' + suffix
```

Comment: What does this have to do with exceptions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You likely mean this:

```
if letter != 'O' or letter != 'Q':
```

The result of your original statement,

```
if letter != 'O' or 'Q':
```

compared `letter` to the result of `'O' or 'Q'`, which is a boolean (true to be exact) (so you could see why this comparison would always be true as it was).

Comment: So how can I fix it to add 'u' between prefix and suffix when letter is O or Q?

Comment: @30trix: Change the `or` to `and`. Or else you can use `if letter not in 'OQ':`; whichever seems clearer to you, I suppose.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with this answer: 1) as pointed out by @Ondrej Kupka, the inequality comparison is evaluated first, and then the boolean one. `or` has a lower precedence than `!=`; 2) `letter != 'O' or letter != 'Q'` is always `True`. Operator precedence summary table:  http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary

Answer (score 5):

Please note that

```
if letter != 'O' or 'Q':
```

is in fact

```
if (letter != 'O') or 'Q':
```

That is probably not what you wanted.

Just a small test on top of it:

```
>>> True != False or True
True
>>> (True != False) or True
True
>>> True != (False or True)
False
```

Note: This means that the answer marked on top is not true, letter is not compared to the result of O or Q...

Answer (score 2):

Python is not COBOL or some other language which supports this syntax. As a start I would suggest you read [Expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html).

Now coming back to your problem, what you expect from the statement

```
if letter != 'O' or 'Q':
```

definitely

```
if letter != 'O' or letter != 'Q':
```

interestingly Python allows you to think laterally. For example you might also say,

```
letter not in ['O','Q']
```

or simply

```
letter not in 'OQ': #In Python Notation
```

or can be more expressive like

```
if all(letter != x for x in 'OQ'):
```

Just compare the above mentioned syntax and usage with yours

When you wrote

```
if letter != 'O' or 'Q':
```

which in Python should be written as

```
if letter not in 'OQ':
```

or may even be

```
if all(letter != x for x in 'OQ'):
```

Comment: I slightly adjusted a couple of your examples so that they would actually work.